# Why am I getting no context user error in tcl?

Tags: tcl

I am getting No context user error when  I 
 try to run

```
list policy * select type;
```

following query in tcl Mql

Comment: More context on what you are trying to do would help people understand what's possibly wrong.

Comment: Are you logged on as anyone?

Comment: I am trying to load types from policies ... No I am not logged in as any particular user

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set context user $user pass $password;list policy...

Answer (score 1):

Log In as a User U might not have permission to run this query